# Agenda/Cron repeat after every 2 week on monday and tuesday

Tags: node.js, cron, agenda

Does agenda/cron support repeat for this scenario?
example : repeat a job every 2 week on monday and tuesday, i am able to repeat a job every 2 week but not a particular days, if yes what will be the expression of time interval. Both week and days can be dynamic.
Thanks

Comment: Useful link to [construct cron sentences](https://crontab.guru/#0_8_*/1,*/14_*_1,2). The cron syntax in that link is the closest I could get to what you are describing. This link also describes what you are constructing, very handy

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the [documentation](https://github.com/agenda/agenda) agenda provides the ability to schedule with `cron` syntax. So for example something like this:

```
await agenda.every('*/3 * * * *', 'delete old users');
```

> Should set agenda to run every 3 minutes.

In your case it is just a matter of finding the correct cron string. Like this for example:

**0 0 */15 * 1-2**

> At 00:00 on every 15th day-of-month if it's on every day-of-week from Monday through Tuesday.

```
await agenda.every('**0 0 */15 * 1-2**', 'do your thing');
```

Try it and see if it does what you would need.